# Build NuGet package for multiple framework targets from Visual Studio 2010 project file

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, nuget

Internally within my organisation we maintain a code library, some of our applications are built on .NET 4 while older applications are still built on .NET 3.5.

We have build configurations that target either the .NET 4 or .NET 3.5 framework and this works as expected. We hit a problem when we want to build NuGet packages that include the output from each build configuration into a single nupkg file (since a NuGet package can support multiple framework targets).

Has anybody come up with a solution to automate this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a good look around I found my solution by looking at how the [Autofac](http://code.google.com/p/autofac/) project handled the problem.

From this I have built a solution using MSBuild.

Comment: The best answer would be to look at their build file http://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/src/Packages.build

Essentially they do builds for each framework version, copy all the libs into the NuGet package structure before finally executing the NuGet build.

This is off the top of my head as I've been out of the .Net development game for several months now.

Comment: @Tim: i have to agree, this needs more content to be helpful.

Comment: links are broken... not very useful

Comment: @wickdninja why not suggest an update, was correct when written 7 years ago.

Comment: @wickdninja you are welcome to edit, I've not been involved with .Net for years and have no interest in updating.